# Solving $\frac1{x-2} + \frac1{x-1} > \frac1x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics, fractions, rational-functions

> $$\frac1{x-2} + \frac1{x-1} > \frac1x$$

My attempt:

I solved it and got $\frac{-x^2+5x-5}{(x-2)(x-1)(x) }> 0$
But after this I am unable to proceed as the numerator has no real roots. So please guide me how shall I proceed.

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{x^2-2}{(x-2)(x-1)x}>0$

Comment: @Calvin Khor, Yes you are right I just found that I have done wrong.

Comment: Even if the numerator had no real roots, you would want to consider the sign of your expression in $x<0$ and $0<x<1$ and $1<x<2$ and $2<x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x \notin \{0,1,2\}$,

$$\frac1{x-2}+\frac1{x-1} > \frac1x$$

- If $x>2$, then each terms are positive, then clearly it is true.

Now, we focus on $x < 2$, that is $x-2<0$.

$$\frac1{x-1}-\frac1x > \frac1{2-x}$$

$$\frac{2-x}{x(x-1)}>1$$

$$\frac{2-x-x(x-1)}{x(x-1)}>0$$

$$\frac{2-x^2}{x(x-1)}>0$$

- If $2-x^2 > 0$, then $x(x-1)>0$. that is $ -\sqrt2 < x < \sqrt2$ and ($x<0$ or $x>1$). That is we obtain $(-\sqrt2, 0) \cup (1, \sqrt2)$.
- If $2-x^2 < 0$, then $x(x-1) <0$, that is $|x| > \sqrt2$ and $0\le x \le 1$, of which no such value exists.

Hence in summary, $(-\sqrt2, 0) \cup (1, \sqrt2)\cup (2, \infty)$.

Comment: Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

Actually,$$\frac1{x-2}+\frac1{x-1}-\frac1x=\frac{x^2-2}{x(x-1)(x-2)}.$$Besides:

- $x^2-2>0$ if and only if $x\in\left(-\infty,-\sqrt2\right)\cup\left(\sqrt2,\infty\right)$;
- $x^2-2<0$ if and only if $x\in\left(-\sqrt2,\sqrt2\right)$;
- $x(x-1)(x-2)>0$ if and only if $x\in(0,1)\cup(2,\infty)$;
- $x(x-1)(x-2)<0$ if and only if $x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(1,2)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks a lot José Carlos Santos for your kind help.

Comment: Yes I can solve now

Comment: @JMP I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality becomes
$$\frac1{x-2}+\frac1{x-1}-\frac1x=\frac{x^2-2}{x(x-1)(x-2)}>0~~~~(1)$$
$$ F=Sign \frac{x^2-2}{x(x-1)(x-2)} = Sign [(x+\sqrt{2})x(x-1)(x-\sqrt{2})(x-2)]~~~~(2)$$
For real values of $x$ (1) and (2) are equivalent to $F>0$ by wavy curve method we get that all real values of $x$ are given by: $$ (-\sqrt{2};0) \cup (1;\sqrt{2}) \cup (2; \infty)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: You are welcome.